# Naive Bayes Classifier -- documents of very different lengths

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to build a Naive Bayes classifier that takes a document and, treating the document as a bag of words and different books as individual classes, gives the probability that the document is that book (I know this is a little ridiculous but it's a starting point for something else).  I am using this:  http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/naivebayes.pdf  as my go-to for how to do this.

So, for example, if we had document d as "The Return of Sherlock Holmes", then looking at a bunch of p(b|d) for a bunch of books, "The Return of Sherlock Holmes" would be high up, as would "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes", while James Joyce's "Ulysses" would be much less probable.

To do this, I'm doing `p(b|d) α p(d|b)p(b)`, where `p(b) = 1/(# of books)` and `p(d|b)=sum over all words w in document[log(p(w|b))]`, where `p(w|b) = (# of times word w appears in book b + 1)/(# of words in book b + vocabularysize)`.

The problem is that, when I run this, it usually gets the right book as the first result, and sometimes gives similar books as high results, but it tends to populate the top results with the same collection of really long books, and the least probable books are always poems, essays, and short stories.  When I run it on one of those short stories, it still has all the short documents, including the one I was looking at, with the lowest or near the lowest un-normalized probabilities, and the most probable books are still the really long ones.  So this model sort of works, in that if a book is long enough the weight given to it from its having the right words will be sufficient to put it on top, but if a book is too short then that weight won't be sufficient and it will still be near the bottom, dominated by the sheer length of the other books.

Why is this happening and how can I fix my model so that it doesn't happen?

Comment: While you are implementing this as a machine-learning exercise, I think the inherent answer to your question is a mathematical one based on probabilities.  You might have better luck on the Mathematics StackExchange site.  If you think it is due to some error/implementation of your code, then you should probably share the problematic bit of code.

Comment: I thought about that, but I saw a lot of Naive Bayes questions on here and none of them suggested moving to Math StackExchange.  This is more of an algorithm-related question than a math question so I think it's more appropriate for it to be here, as StackOverflow covers not just programming but also algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Very long books will have many words. Naive Bayes will favor these documents because all the words you are using in your input are likely to have occurred numerous times in very long books. Because its a feature vector (and I assume you are using unigrams) the order of the words does not matter. So the words in your input may get matched to a long book simply because the words showed up all over that really long book.

1) If you want good probabilities, you should step away from naive bayes. The independence assumption leads to very bad probability results. There are [many papers](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs276/handouts/rennie.icml03.pdf) about its issues with respect to its probability values.

2) Order of magnitude changes in document length can be difficult to deal with. You can look up the cosine similarity function for a number of explanations as to why we use normalization when dealing with text - and try applying it to your feature vectors.

3) If you want to stick with naive bays, you might want to try using the Bernoulli distribution instead of Multinomial. It should be less effected by the word counts / document length, since that seems to be your issue.

4) You will probably want to apply [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) to your corpus.

Assuming you are teaching yourself, treating this is a standard classification problem is a good start. If you get more interested in the particular task you are tackling - you may want to look into author identification, which is very closely related to what you are trying to do (given a text, identify who wrote the text - where you are saying given a text, identify the book it came from). In your case the "authors" would instead be the books that the text came from.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard problem with the multinomial classifier, as Raff mentions, due to the larger documents swamping total counts in training. It seems that you're getting the correct result as the top class most of the time, but you want the posterior to be accurate? Naive Bayes is a very bad probability model, hoping for a realistic posterior is highly unlikely.

Better probability models for documents are the Dirichlet Compound Multinomial, and Latent Dirichlet Allocation. These are both generative. Since you're just interested in the posterior over classes, you should consider a discriminative model. The discriminative version of Naive Bayes is MaxEnt/Logistic Regression/a Log-Linear model (these are all the same thing but you may hear one term used or another). You could also use an SVM with Platt's method for getting a probability, or a Neural Net with a softmax output and cross-entropy loss. For the discriminative models, I'd recommend you normalise your counts by the sum of words in each document too, since this will make all documents count equally. You can't do this for the generative models, however, as they're defined for count data.

Answer (score 0):

Your denominator in `p(w|b)` seems strange. You should try to use just the

`p(w|b) = (# of times word w appears in book b + 1)/(# of words in book b)`

Comment: No, his denominator is correct. If you follow your suggestion your probabilities will not sum to one.